# Coefficients of general Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know how to compute coefficients of Fourier Series on an interval of $2\pi$. But in this case I need to find the sine series of $f(x)=b$ on the interval $x \in [-L,L]$. Can someone please let me know if the procedure for finding coefficients in this case is about the same, i.e. I can use the same formulae as for finding $a_n$ and $b_n$ on the interval of $2\pi$? Namely, $b_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos(nx)dx$? I have doubts about that.
I tried to find $b_n$ using the complex form, but got $c_n = 0$, which shouldn't be the case.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ periodic with period $2L,$ it's Fourier series is
$$\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n \cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)} + b_n \sin{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}},$$
where
$$a_0=\frac{1}{L}\int
\limits_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx, \\
a_n = \frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx,\\
b_n = \frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx.$$